# How to loop with string formatting in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have two variables that I am constructing a  new string from, however one of the variables isn't looping correctly.  I am expecting several values, but the resultant output is the first values from the sequence.  How can I construct/place the string formatting correctly so that it correctly loops through either variable properly?  If I move my string formatting to either loop, then it loops properly, i.e. if it is in count, then the counts appear correctly, but items do not.

Code:

```
for dSr in lServiceRequests:
            dListOfLa311ElectronicWaste = dSr["ListOfLa311ElectronicWaste"]
            if("La311ElectronicWaste" in dListOfLa311ElectronicWaste):
                lLa311ElectronicWaste = dListOfLa311ElectronicWaste["La311ElectronicWaste"]
                for dla311ElectronicWaste in lLa311ElectronicWaste:
                    v_ewaste_item_count= dla311ElectronicWaste[K_ewaste_Item_Count]
                    print v_ewaste_item_count
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
2
Computers
Laptops/Tablets
Cell Phone
TV (Any Size)
1
1
1
2
Computers
Laptops/Tablets
Cell Phone
TV (Any Size)
1
1
1
2
Computers
Laptops/Tablets
Cell Phone
TV (Any Size)
1
1
1
2
Computers
Laptops/Tablets
Cell Phone
TV (Any Size)
1
1
1
2
Computers
Laptops/Tablets
Cell Phone
TV (Any Size)
1
1
1
2
Computers
Laptops/Tablets
Cell Phone
TV (Any Size)
1
1
1
2
Computers
Laptops/Tablets
Cell Phone
TV (Any Size)
1
1
1
2
Computers
Laptops/Tablets
Cell Phone
TV (Any Size)
1
1
1
2
Computers
Laptops/Tablets
Cell Phone
TV (Any Size)
```

Code with list comprehension:

```
  for dSr in lServiceRequests:
            k_ewaste_info = ' '
            dListOfLa311ElectronicWaste = dSr["ListOfLa311ElectronicWaste"]
            if("La311ElectronicWaste" in dListOfLa311ElectronicWaste):
                lLa311ElectronicWaste = dListOfLa311ElectronicWaste["La311ElectronicWaste"]
                for dla311ElectronicWaste in lLa311ElectronicWaste:
                    v_ewaste_type = dla311ElectronicWaste[K_ewaste_type]
                    # print v_ewaste_type
                    v_ewaste_item_info = '{0},  {1} '.format(v_ewaste_item_count, v_ewaste_type)
                    if k_ewaste_info != v_ewaste_item_info:
                        k_ewaste_info = v_ewaste_item_info
                        print v_ewaste_item_info
```

Output from list comprehension:

```
2,  Computers 
2,  Laptops/Tablets 
2,  Cell Phone 
2,  TV (Any Size) 
2,  Computers 
2,  Laptops/Tablets 
2,  Cell Phone 
2,  TV (Any Size) 
2,  Computers 
2,  Laptops/Tablets 
2,  Cell Phone 
2,  TV (Any Size) 
2,  Computers 
2,  Laptops/Tablets 
2,  Cell Phone 
2,  TV (Any Size) 
2,  Computers 
2,  Laptops/Tablets 
2,  Cell Phone 
2,  TV (Any Size) 
2,  Computers 
2,  Laptops/Tablets 
2,  Cell Phone 
2,  TV (Any Size) 
2,  Computers 
2,  Laptops/Tablets 
2,  Cell Phone 
2,  TV (Any Size) 
2,  Computers 
2,  Laptops/Tablets 
2,  Cell Phone 
2,  TV (Any Size) 
2,  Computers 
2,  Laptops/Tablets 
2,  Cell Phone 
2,  TV (Any Size)
```

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding this correctly, but are you showing us the code that is using the result of the list comprehensions? Why not show us the actual list comprehensions?

Comment: The code using the list comprehensions is above.   `v_ewaste_item_info = '{0},  {1} '.format(v_ewaste_item_count, v_ewaste_type)`

Comment: I don't see any list comprehensions in the code you posted.

Comment: my bad, it's a dictionary comprehension, is it clear on what I am trying to accomplish??

Comment: I don't see a dictionary comprehension either.

Comment: what would this be called then? `{0}, {1} '.format(v_ewaste_item_count, v_ewaste_type)`

Comment: String formatting. Edit: List comprehension `[x for x in range(5)]`. Dictionary comprehension: `{x: my_items[x] for x in range(5)}`.

Comment: Also I don't see the `v_ewaste_item_count` variable used or declared anywhere.

Comment: It's there. The first code example shows where it is declared.  The second code example just takes into account the string formatting.

Comment: String formatting is just putting the variables in a string so if the string you are printing is not what you expect then there is something wrong with your logic. This isn't a "string formatting" problem (at least I doubt it).